# Adding logos into fields

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, images

Long shot, but does anyone know how Spekit is able to add their logo to every single field in Salesforce?

Would like to add my own logos into fields such as Picklist, Text, Formulas etc to show to the client these were made by our team.

Would like to do this without the need to create a visualforce page and reference each field and embed an image.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess since I don't use Spekit but I'd say they use custom lightning components.

You can check that by visiting Setup/Installed packages/Spekit/View components

Answer (score 1):

Spekit uses a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spekit/nbphjjmibhopfgkkbpoggemjnihnchhk?hl=en-US). With chrome extension you can definitely override or overlay things on top of Salesforce experience.